# How to open multiple projects in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How to open multiple projects at time in VS2010?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Visual Studio has two "project" buckets to structure your work. The top level is called the solution level. One solution can have any number of projects. So, create a solution, and add your projects to your solution. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee817674(pandp.10).aspx. Although the article is outdated, the concepts still apply

Answer (score 17):

1. Have several instances of VS (this may tax your RAM, but it is no problem if you have 2 GB or more, I often have several Visual Studios with large solutions started)
2. Add the projects you want to have opened to one solution (right click the solution in Solution explorer, it is there).

Comment: +1 Adding it to one solution is the best way to go given that the projects are related.